# LWJGL shader won't compile and has no errors

Tags: java, 3d, glsl, shader, lwjgl

I'm new to the glsl shader language and to lwjgl. I just threw together this program and the shaders won't compile. It doesn't output a shader log, and I don't know what's wrong.
Shader loader (It throws the error) :

```
    public static int generateShader(String shaderFile, int type)
    {
        StringBuilder shaderSource = new StringBuilder();
        try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("res/shaders/" + shaderFile));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                shaderSource.append(line + "\n");
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        int shaderId = GL20.glCreateShader(type);
        GL20.glShaderSource(shaderId, shaderSource.toString());
        GL20.glCompileShader(shaderId);
        if(GL20.glGetShaderi(shaderId, GL20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == 0)
        {
            System.out.println(GL20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderId, 1000));
            System.err.println("Could not compile shader");
            System.exit(1);
        }

    return shaderId;
}
```

Here's my basic vertex shader (It is the one that is being compiled):

```
#version 400 core

in vec3 position;

out vec3 color;

void main(void)
{
    gl_position = vec4(position, 1);
    color = position;
}
```

Here is how I store my shaders:

```
public abstract class Shader {

private int shader;
private int geometry;
private int vertex;
private int fragment;

public Shader()
{
    shader = GL20.glCreateProgram();
    if (shader == 0){
        System.err.println("Could not find valid memory location for shader");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

public void start()
{
    GL20.glUseProgram(shader);
}

public void stop()
{
    GL20.glUseProgram(0);
}

protected abstract void bindAttributes();

protected void bindAttribute(int attrib, String name)
{
    GL20.glBindAttribLocation(shader, attrib, name);
}

public void finalize()
{
    bindAttributes();
    GL20.glLinkProgram(shader);
    GL20.glValidateProgram(shader);
}

public void loadVertex(String fileName)
{
    vertex = ResourceLoader.generateShader(fileName, GL20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GL20.glAttachShader(shader, vertex);
}

public void loadFragment(String fileName)
{
    fragment = ResourceLoader.generateShader(fileName, GL20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    GL20.glAttachShader(shader, fragment);
}

public void loadGeometry(String fileName)
{
    geometry = ResourceLoader.generateShader(fileName, GL32.GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER);
    GL20.glAttachShader(shader, geometry);
}

}
```

It errors out when I call loadVertex. As I said before, there is no java errors and the shader info log is empty.

Comment: [`glGetShaderInfoLog(int, int)`](http://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/opengl/GL20.html#glGetShaderInfoLog%28int,%20int%29) returns the log as a String. You have to print it yourself: `System.err.println(GL20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderId, 1000));`.

Comment: Thanks. I miss obvious stuff like that a lot. Now I can see that I am getting a premature end of file error. Any tips?

Comment: What is the exact error log you get? Maybe you could also mark the line where the error occurs in the post.

Comment: Thanks. I just figured it out. I wasn't getting an error before, but I thought it was in my vertex shader. I just realized that it is my fragment shader, because I'm an idiot, and I found out that I accidentally did two open brackets instead of an open and a close one. Sorry for taking your time away. I miss a lot of obvious stuff like that.